# error 'TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, firebase

```
    useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('likes')
      .doc(slug)
      .get()
      .then(res => {
        if (!res.data()) {
          console.log('No matching document');
        } else {
          setLikes(res.data().likes);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n96FA.png)

How can I solve the error. I'm trying to rebuild a web app example that uses Firebase Cloud Functions and Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `!res.data()` will not tell Typescript that `res.data()` will not return undefined.

You would either have to store the result, and then type guard it:

```js
.then(res => { // res is a DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>
  const data = res.data(); // data is DocumentData | undefined
  if (!data) {
    console.log('No matching document');
  } else {
    setLikes(data.likes); // data is DocumentData
  }
})
```

or, you can use [`DataSnapshot#exists`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#exists) instead (preferred):

```js
.then(res => { // res is a DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>
  if (!res.exists) {
    console.log('No matching document');
  } else {
    setLikes(res.data().likes); // res is treated as a QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData> (res.data() always returns DocumentData)
  }
})
```

Relevant API Reference:

- [`DocumentSnapshot#exists`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#exists)
- [`DocumentSnapshot#data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data)
- [`QueryDocumentSnapshot#data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#data)

Answer (score -1):

Because of res.data is a function which can return undefined, from a typescript's perspective, it's always possible that the result of a call would be undefined.

So, you can assign the result of `res.data()!` to a variable and then use it instead of `res.data()`.

Comment: Using it directly as res.data() or assigning to a variable is one and the same thing.

Comment: You didn't get the context.
Please, read the problem again.
I didn't say that res.data() and const data = res.data() will give you different values.

We have TWO calls of res.data() function.
If we write 
if(res.data()){ 
 const data = res.data() 
}, 
res.data() inside if block will still return nullable value.

BUT, if we write 
const data = res.data();
if(data){ ... do something with data }
the value of data variable would be non-nullable.

Comment: @sandpat Here is example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQMpwLaoCICGUBAFAJQBciASqhHAE4AmAPAWAJ4A0i7HAfIgA+icE1TAYYVE0QBvAFABIBuhAMkAWSIALAHQN2THOUSCADHoDMiAPzyAvoipiJUmQG4FDhb4D0fogAogAeBNgADgA2qIgAjAowwCRomDj4RKRkZIpK9GAAzlCITJmIALwo6Fi4hMTkXkqlxADaAOQA1qgcbQC6FYhtAG4EUSCobV4+CgHBYZExiABMCvlFJWWVqTUZ9WSJyc0EOcpH7V09-ZXDo+OT3kA